# How should i replicate database table into equivalent java bean class which can be used in spring boot rest api?

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, rest

My database table name is **seller** which has columns **seller_id**(PK)(Auto Increment),**seller_name**,**seller_email** etc..
 
Here is java bean class **SellerBean**

```
public class SellerBean {

    private Integer sellerId;
    private String sellerName;
    private String sellerEmail;
    ....

    //Constructor & Getters-Setters

}
```

I have created a rest api method for seller registration and used **Swagger** for api documentation

```
@RestController
public class SellerRestController {

    @Autowired
    SellerService sellerService;

    @RequestMapping(value="seller/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<SellerBean> registerSeller(@RequestBody SellerBean sellerBean){
        SellerBean seller = sellerService.registerSeller(sellerBean);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(seller,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Here the problem is that when i check this method via swagger UI , this method asks for json which contains all the field of SellerBean , But i don't want sellerId(PK)(AI) to be asked(or to be entered by user)
Is there any way to restrict any field of bean to be asked for (or to be entered) ?
(I have to keep that sellerId in the SellerBean because i have performed all the CRUD operations via that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using JPA.

Here is an small exemple:

First, you need to create your entity which is the "mirror" of your database table:

```
@Entity(name = "Seller")
@Table(name = "SELLER") // your table name
public class Seller {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id") // your column name
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String sellerName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String sellerEmail;

    ...
}
```

Then you can use JpaReporitory and CrudRepository interface which will do what you want:

```
@Repository
public interface Repository<Seller> extends JpaRepository<Seller, Long> {
}
```

Then a DAO:

```
public class SellerDaoImpl implements SellerDao {

    SellerRepository repository;

    public SellerDaoImpl(SellerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Seller create(Seller toCreate) {
        return this.repository.save(toCreate);
    }
}
```

Your service should look like:

```
public SellerServiceImpl implements SellerService {

    SellerMapper mapper;
    SellerDao dao;

    public SellerServiceImpl(SellerMapper mapper, SellerDao dao) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public SellerDto registerSeller(SellerDto toRegister) {
        Seller entity = this.mapper.mapDto(toRegister);
        return this.mapper.mapEntity(this.dao.create(entity));
    }
}
```

Your DTO (basicaly your SellerBean):

```
public class SellerDto {
   private String sellerName;
   private String sellerEmail;
   ...
}
```

And your mapper:

```
public class SellerMapper {
    public SellerDto mapEntity(Seller entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        }
        SellerDto dto = new SellerDto();
        dto.setSellerName(entity.getSellerName());
        dto.setSellerEmail(entity.getSellerEmail());
        ...
        return dto;
    }

    public Seller mapDto(SellerDto dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Seller entity = new Seller();
        entity.setSellerName(dto.getSellerName());
        entity.setSellerEmail(dto.getSellerEmail());
        ...
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Don't forget about Bean's configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = SellerRepository.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = SellerConfiguration.class)
public class SellerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SellerModelMapper sellerModelMapper() {
        return new SellerModelMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public SellerDao sellerDao(SellerRepository repository) {
        return new SellerDao(repository);
    }

    @Bean
    public SellerService sellerService(SellerMapper mapper, SellerDao dao) {
        return new SellerService(mapper, dao);
    }
}
```